# Is there anything like CSS's Z-Index in Objective C?

Tags: css, objective-c, cocoa, z-index

I have a game, and I would like to control whether the character is in front of another element on screen, or behind it, with something like the Z-Index in CSS.  Do you know of anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the NSView's documentation (if you work with views). There is e.g.

`- (void)sortSubviewsUsingFunction:(NSComparisonResult (*)(id, id, void *))compare context:(void *)context`

> Orders the receiver's immediate subviews using the specified
>   comparator function.

or if you work with layers there is a property called `zPosition` that does the job

> The default value of this property is 0. Changing the value of this
>   property changes the the front-to-back ordering of layers onscreen.
>   This can affect the visibility of layers whose frame rectangles
>   overlap.

Answer (score 1):

If your target platform is iOS and you are talking about `UIView`s (not OpenGL for example), you can manage their hierarchy (order in which they are drawn) using these `UIView`'s methods:

```
– addSubview:
– bringSubviewToFront:
– sendSubviewToBack:
– removeFromSuperview
– insertSubview:atIndex:
– insertSubview:aboveSubview:
– insertSubview:belowSubview:
– exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:
```

You can find complete info in [UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-DontLinkElementID_5) under the **Managing the View Hierarchy** header